# Need help identifying set from 2011

Tags: piece-information, set-identification

Bag came with no instructions. Just these 103 pcs[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Going from the Tan Panel 2 x 2 x 1 Corner (# 91501), I've dug into bricklink: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=91501&in=S

This particular piece has only been in 9 sets, and the one I can see that matches the rest of the pieces is [10692-1: Creative Bricks](https://brickset.com/sets/10692-1/Creative-Bricks)

[image]